# Identityserver4 database, token and production

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I implemented EF for identity server following this link
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework

I see many tables/entities but not even single table for tokens. 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Entities

Is it correct behavior for production? How can I get token in database or it is not needed even on production?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PersistedGrants table is where your tokens would be stored. Keep in mind only reference tokens, refresh tokens and authorization code is being saved for security reasons. You will see entries in this table once user logs in successfully. see [this](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/deployment.html) for further refrences!

You can also implement your own implementation for the grant store and add it in your startup like this:

```
services.AddTransient<IPersistedGrantStore, MyPersistedGrantStore>
```